# How to get Kubernetes UI in localmachine?

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, azure-vm-scale-set, kubeadm

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in Azure on 3 CentOS 7 machines. I'm treating those machines as a bare-metal cluster to do some test. I'm using kubeadm for spinning the cluster. Now my question is how can I see the Kubernetes UI in my local machine for the cluster running in Azure private n/w. I have the cluster running and nodes registered which I can see in CentOS 7 terminal by running "kubectl get-nodes".

Any insights would be helpful, please shed some light on how to get that work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cluster up and running.Now if you want to access the kubernetes-dashboard which is part of kube-system namespaces.Apply following commands to access the dashboard.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

You will copy the name of the pod of kubernetes-dashboard and replace it with the following command

```
 kubectl -n kube-system port-forward NAME-OF-k8s-Dashboard-POD 9090:9090
```

It will create TCP-Proxy and you can access it on http://localhost:9090

***There is another way to access the dashboard***

you can use following command

```
kubectl proxy --port=8001
```

Now you can access it on 
 http://localhost:8001/ui

Answer (score 0):

> how can I see the kubernetes UI in my localmachine for the cluster
>   running in azure private n/w.

We can use Azure CLI 2.0 to make a remote connection to Azure kubernetes.

First, we should install kubectl:

```
az acs kubernetes install-cli
```

Then download cluster credentials:

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=<cluster-resource-group> --name=<cluster-name>
```

Then we can use `kubectl` command to get k8s information, like `kubectl get nodes`.

After connect to Azure k8s, we can launch the kubernetes web UI with this command:

```
az acs kubernetes browse -g [Resource Group] -n [Container service instance name]
```

Like this:

[image]

More information about **make a remote connection** to Azure ACS K8S, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-connect#connect-to-a-kubernetes-cluster).

More information about using **the kubernetes web UI** with Azure container service, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-ui).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)